# Set conditional constraint, Pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

First time using pulp and I am trying to set a conditional constraint on a production problem I am working on. Unfortunately I cannot find any examples in the documentation as to how to do so either.

The objective function is to maximise revenue by informing monthly plant production on which product to produce based on the forecast price per product minus costs (Naturally there are lots of other constraints omitted here, otherwise it would be far simpler).

For the below data I need to set the following constraints:

1. A plant can only produce a single product each month, despite having the capability to produce multiple products.

that limits a plant to producing only ONE product in a month. I am quite new to pulp but despite trawling the documentation and S.O. I cannot find an example implementation.

Production data:

[image: production data]

[image: product forecast price data]

My code so far

```
# omitted data etl logic - it is formatted as per the above images

# Get production info
plants = LpVariable.dicts('plants',
    ((month, plant, product) for month, plant, product in wp_df.index if month >= 4),
    lowBound = 0,
    cat='Integer')

# Get forecast price info by product
forecast_prices =  LpVariable.dicts('price_by_prod',
    ((month, contract) for month, contract in fcst_diffs.index if month >= 4),
    lowBound = 0,
    cat='Integer') 

# Prod costs for each month, plant.
costs = LpVariable.dicts(
    'prod costs',
    ((month, plant) for month, plant in prod_costs_df.index),
    lowBound=0,
    cat='Integer')

# Define problem
model = LpProblem('Revenue Maximising Production Optimisation',
                  LpMaximize)

# Define objective function
model += lpSum(
    [plants[m,w,g] * wp_df.loc[(m,w,g), 'production_output'] for m, w, g in wp_df.index]
    + [costs[m, w] * costs_df.loc[(m,w), 'prod_costs_usd'] for m, w in prod_costs_df.index]
)
```

I am omitting constraints for now as I have quite a few to set.

Appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a set of binary variables which are indexed by {plant, product, month}, which determine whether plant `i` is being used to make product `j` during month `k`. Variable will be `1` when this is true, and `0` otherwise.

You'll then need to add constraints so that the *amount* of product `j` being produced in plant `i` during month `k` is limited. Typically this could be done with a constraint constraining this *amount* variable to be `<= b*C` where `b` is the binary variable, and C is the capacity of that plant to make that product.

Finally you need to constraint each plant to only make a single product during each month. For each month, and for each plant, the sum of these binary variables across all the products is limited to be `<= 0`.

Good luck!

Comment: The aim of this optimisation would be to make this choice of product based on the constraint (1 product only) and the forecast product premium i.e. make the decision based on the forecast price? do you know if this is possible? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible. What I'm suggesting above is introducing binary variables. The value of these variables would be selected as part of the optimisation. Incorporating a forecast is just a case of including that in your objective function - depending on the type of forecast you have you might also need to decide how to deal with the uncertainty of the forecast.

Comment: Thank you Kabdulla -  would you perhaps have an example as code please? for example, how to set the variable dicts and constraints?

Comment: If you modify your question to include a [mcve] i.e. code that generates a minimal toy example then I'd be happy to.

Comment: @kabulla I have changed the question here slightly and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349492/pulp-transport-constraint?noredirect=1#comment108554026_61349492, would you be happy to help? many thanks for your patience

Comment: @cmp it's generally better to correct/edit/update a question than to ask the same question slightly improved elsewhere. Otherwise this will become a dead-end question that recieves no answers and just clogs up SO.